# Security group to allow connection from OpenVPN network

Tags: amazon-web-services, openvpn, nat, security-groups

I am making a openVPN server in my AWS VPC. I want to make a security group that only accept SSH connection from my VPN. I already using my VPC CIDR (10.0.0.0/8), OpenVPN public address, and OpenVPN CIDR(tun0 / 192.168.0.0/30) but not works.

Here is my ifconfig from my OpenVPN Server

```
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 9001
        inet 10.0.0.116  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::8f4:d5ff:fe76:1230  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:f4:d5:76:12:30  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8783395  bytes 5626116552 (5.2 GiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6575989  bytes 5676746788 (5.2 GiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 64  bytes 5920 (5.7 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 64  bytes 5920 (5.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

tun0: flags=4305<UP,POINTOPOINT,RUNNING,NOARP,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.255  destination 192.168.0.2
        inet6 fe80::a316:dc9b:98b8:526  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 100
```

**Update:**

After some trying and error, i found out that i can connect to my instance if the security group is using my ISP address but not my VPN address. Is the problem about NAT?

Comment: If adding your public IP address to the security group changes anything, then you are not actually using the VPN connection.  You need to be connecting to the instance using its private IP.

Comment: But when i am using whatismyip.com it showing my VPN public IP address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, i know i had a mistake in which ip address i should connect. The cause i cannot connect SSH port is i am using ip public to connect. It should be using ip private .